# Javascript // Set margin-top to be negative half of site height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a site where I want the content of each site to be dead center regardless of the screens height.

What i am trying to achieve is something like this:

```
#content {position:absolute; top:50%; height:240px; margin-top:-120px; /* negative half of the height */}
```

And I am not sure how to code this:

```
function fullscreenHeight(){      
      var window_height = $(window).height();
      var negative_margin = window_height / 2 * -1;
      $('.pageclass01').css({height:window_height});
      $('.pageclass01').css({margin-top:negative_margin});
}         
fullscreenHeight();           
$(window).bind('resize',function() {      
    fullscreenHeight();
});
```

Anybody that are able to help me on this one? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
function fullscreenHeight(){
  var window_height = $(window).height();
  var negative_margin = -(window_height / 2);
  $('.pageclass01').css({'height':window_height,'marginTop':negative_margin+'px'});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS:

```css
#content {
    position:fixed;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    height:240px;
    margin:auto;
}
/* the following is just in case of a too-small screen, such as a small phone */
@media screen and (max-height:240px) {
    #content {position:static}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.pageclass01').css({height:window_height,marginTop: "-"+($(this).height()/2)});// this here being the pageclass01 element and not window
```

This is what you may need to do

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(".page-container").outerHeight()< $(window).outerHeight()){
    $(".page-container").css({
        'top' : ($(window).outerHeight()-$(".page-container").outerHeight())/2
    })
} else {
    $(".page-container").css({
        'top' : 0
    })
}
```